# How to create ASP.NET Core MVC project in Visual Studio with pre installed NuGet packages and Data folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I had created ASP.NET 6.0 Core Web App MVC project VS a few weeks back.

[image]

The generated project files looked like this with pre installed NuGet packages

[image]

Now when I create the project the same way I am missing the NuGet packages and Data folder with DbContext and settings for the database in appsettings.json.

[image]

Comment: I think you'll find there are other differences as well. For example, areas have not been scaffolded either. Likely the second project is not being scaffolded with accounts and authentication.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? In addition, `Community` or `Developer package`? Furthermore, please double check the type of project you have created are same.

Comment: I know this might seem odd but did you change Keyboard setting? There used to be a glitch where some Project Types loaded different. Switch to C# Keyboard and try again.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, the second project was not scaffolded with users, but I am asking for the data part of the project and the NuGet packages.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.3.4. The first screenshot of the question shows the type of project I had created both times.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I have never changed them, they are default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you haven't selected the Authentication Type as 'Individual Users' from drop-down menu on 'Additional Information Page' after creating project.

I'll explain through screenshots.

When you select None Like this: [Authentication Type: None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z12xO.jpg) . You'll be missing the NuGet packages and Data folder with DbContext and settings for the database in appsettings.json. Like this: [No Npm packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt4vq.jpg)

And When you'll select 'Individual Users' [Authentication Type: Individual Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6SEG.jpg) It'll be with pre installed NuGet packages and Data folder with DbContext and settings for the database in appsettings.json. Looking like this [Pre installed packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYeEO.jpg)

I hope this helps and solves your problem :)